# How does tulpa communicate with his owner?

Tags: magic, humans, communication, dream

A Tulpa is a concept in mysticism and the paranormal of a being or object which is created through spiritual or mental powers.

The Limbo is like internet, a vast information network made of dreams from humans around the world and tulpas inhabit this worlds, sometimes interacting between them. Humans rarely visit this realm through astral dreams.

Tulpas are created through imagination and desires of the host. They can vary in shape and personality depending on the emotions and information from which they were created, and that is why they can create recurring dreams or nightmares.

How can these creatures communicate indirectly with their humans through the limbo even if we cant remember the whole dream?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. When you have time please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get more information on this community and its culture.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean with astral dream?

Comment: Don't tulpas usually communicate straight to the host? I mean, isn't that the whole point?

Answer (score 4):

**Lucid Dreaming**

Only individuals skilled in lucid dreaming can communicate directly with a Tulpa. If a person is not skilled in lucid dreaming the best they can do is a vague interpretation of normal dreams they have that may or may not be true. For instance, how would I know a dream about an important conversation with a tulpa wasn't actually just purely a construct of my subconscious that had nothing to do with actually contacting them?

So I begin training myself in lucid dreaming so that I can differentiate between a dream I actually control and one that is just a run of the mill dream. Eventually I get good enough that I can just ask a tulpa something that I couldn't possibly know to verify that the contact is real then test it during the day. A possible test might be to have my wife hide my car keys somewhere while I'm out for a walk before bed so there would be no possible way my subconscious could dredge up the answer into my dreams. I ask the Tulpa to tell me where they are, then wake up and find them in that exact spot. Okay, now i know I'm actually in contact with a real Tulpa and that it is communicating real information to me.

Now, Tulpas have names, which act kind of like the magical version of a web address. If a Tulpa wishes to let me remain in contact it gives me that name so I can call it up whenever I'm lucid dreaming to consult it about whatever I need to. Obviously its not an exact science since Tulpas have no binding contract to be honest but its now a lot more accurate than regular dream interpretation that could just turn out to be assigning meaning to random subconscious gibberish.

In this way you add some fun variation in powers to your story, since lucid dreaming is something that can be easily, regularly, and naturally accomplished without effort by some, and a matter of lots of training for others, or even a combination of both. You combine users with natural talent and people with training and people who just cant quite seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Humans make a pact with their Tulpas which allows them to occupy the person's body during their sleep. Now the Tulpas does its best to leave a message for the Human in the physical world. However, their messages tend do use pictures or single words, because Tulpas tend to think in dreams, which are often disjointed or don't work in reality, and they're also not used to having a physical form, which makes them clumsy, plus nobody writes in the dream world so it's very hard for them to find the right written word to use.

Answer (score 3):

**Omens.**

[[image: snake and eagle]]
http://flagstamps.blogspot.com/2013/02/the-year-of-snake-snakes-in-flags.html

Spirits indirectly communicate by sending omens.  These are unusual events which carry meaning beyond the mundane.  Above: the snake and the eagle, a portent which guided the ancient Aztecs in the founding of their city.

Every culture has stories of signs from the gods which humans witness, marvel at, and then use as guidance in their affairs.  This is how the Tulpas would do it.

Answer (score 2):

Since your Tulpas are spiritual forms and the Limbo is made out of human dreams, why not have the Tulpas live in the Limbo like it was an actual city. When a Human dreams they appear in a part of the Limbo and the dreams they see there is what is happening to their subconscious self. When the human starts to dream, they appear physically in the limbo, and a Tulpa can enter into that dream and interact with the humans subconscious to try and send them messages.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe they can plant certain little patterns into our thoughts. I little bit like hypnosis.

So e.g. a Tulpa creates a scenario in a dream where it walks with a human and tells him something. The whole time they talk a certain song is playing. In the "real" world the same song is playing in the radio and suddenly he/she remembers the conversation, parts of it or at least the topic.

Or this song could be the message itself. Like a human has to decide which way to go and suddenly a song with the line "... to the left..." pops into it's head. It heard the song during the dream and the Tulpa made a mental anchor that as soon as you are not certain where to go, you think of the song.

This way you have a nice separation between the dream and the real world and a not so obvious way of communication

Answer (score 0):

They should have multiple ways:

1. Strong feeling of deja vu at a critical moment.
2. Art or documents produced while in a trance
3. Goosebumps!